# Real-time Charts with React-admin

Tags: react-admin

While I have used a number of charts like HighCharts, Charts.js, C3, D3, Has anyone tried or is there some documentation around how to include any of the chart frameworks with React-admin? I looked at a few but looks like we have to do a lot of custom development. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used https://github.com/recharts/recharts and it works great. It has a really good flexible API.